# Cygwin - Serial port listed under /dev but stty reports invalid argument

Tags: windows, arduino, serial-port, cygwin

An Arduino-compatible device enumerates as a virtual COM port on my computer, but `stty` reports an error and `cat` does not receive anything from it.

```sh
~$ ls -al /dev/ttyS14
crw-rw-rw- 1 user.name None 117, 14 Feb 15 16:26 /dev/ttyS14

~$ stty.exe -F /dev/ttyS14 57600 cs8
stty: /dev/ttyS14: Invalid argument
```

Now, opening the port (COM15) with Putty works fine. After closing Putty, stty works as expected without reporting an error:

```sh
~$ stty.exe -F /dev/ttyS14 57600 cs8
```

The same goes for `cat` which now receives data from the port. Presumably Putty knows how to initialize these ports correctly under Windows/Cygwin.

I am trying to automate my workflow but this manual step is preventing me from doing so.

Any idea ?

Comment: In my case, I found that this issue seems to depend on the COM port number. I had no problems as long as my port number was less than 10 (or 16?), but with a high port number, I saw this problem. The solution in the answers worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with PI usb gadget.  Executing this seems to fix it for me (example for cygwin /dev/ttyS6):

```
cmd /c mode com7 baud=115200 parity=n data=8
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. In my case the issue arose inside a test script that causes the attached device to disconnect and reconnect. It seems that Cygwin can only open the port again after it has been reopened/reconfigured by some Windows command.

In my case, just specifying a `baudrate` sufficed – the actual baud rate specified does not seem to matter, since, in my case, it will be re-initialised by Cygwin later on, anyway.

```
COMPORT=COM7
cmd /c mode $COMPORT baud=9600
```